# accordion fix (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

HTML

```
<h2 class="sec-title">one</h2>
<div class="sec-content">content 1</div>
<h2 class="sec-title">two</h2>
<div class="sec-content">content 2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.sec-content').hide();
$('.sec-title:first').addClass('active').next().show();

$('.sec-title').click(function(){
 if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
  $('.sec-title').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
  $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); 
 }
 return false;
});
```

... works but what if want to make the second accordion section active on pageload? what do I change?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `make the second accordion section active ` what it actually means ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line where you select the first `sec-title` class element to this:

```
$('.sec-title:eq(1)').addClass('active').next().show();
```

Here's the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for the `:eq` selector.  I think it will do what you want.  It will select the nth element that matches the selector.  Remember that `eq()` is 0-based - so `:eq(1)` is selecting the second item that has the `sec-title` class.

Here's my fiddle that illustrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/7KdGn/1/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may use (jQuery UI Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) instead of reinventing the wheel. Pay close attention to its [active](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active) option. Then your code will become simplified to as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });
});​
```

Take a look for an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5RYyK/).